# How to upgrade Mac OS X from 10.6.8 to 10.9?

Tags: macos, macbook

I read the following informations from the [apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-2139):

> Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks, breaks the tradition, and is available free
>   (subject certain license restrictions) for anyone from 10.6.8 through
>   10.8.5 as long as they meet the system requirements for 10.8

I have Mac with OS 10.6.8 and I want to upgrade my OS to 10.9. and according to above information this is possible. But I do not how to do that with my Mac.

Could you tell me how to upgrade my Mac OS X from 10.6.8 to 10.9?

Comment: Apple Store, and choose Mavericks?

Comment: http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/ You can probably just click on 'Upgrade Now' at the top right.

Answer (score 1):

From your error message it sounds as if you have older hardware.

Check Mavericks hardware requirements http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5842

compatible models:

- iMac (Mid-2007 or later)
- MacBook (13-inch Aluminum, Late 2008), (13-inch, Early 2009 or later)
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid-2009 or later),
- MacBook Pro (15-inch or 17-inch, Mid/Late 2007 or later)
- MacBook Air (Late 2008 or later)
- Mac mini (Early 2009 or later)
- Mac Pro (Early 2008 or later)
- Xserve (Early 2009)

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the Mavericks installer from the App Store? If not, just open the app store, download the Mavericks installer and try running it.

If you have tried this and it does not work please post the error message you get here.

Comment: I get error "we could not complete your purchase, OS Marvix could not be installed on this computer" and the learn more button show this web page: support.apple.com/kb/HT5842

Comment: seems to be hardware problem because I have macbook 2007